# Electron: difference between process.defaultApp and app.isPackaged

Tags: electron

What is a the difference between [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) flags [`process.defaultApp`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processdefaultapp) and [`app.isPackaged`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appispackaged)? Both are used to distinguish dev and production environment. My observation is that `Boolean(process.defaultApp) == !app.isPackaged` always. **Are there any cases, when both are `true` or both are `false`?**

From doc and code:

#### process.defaultApp

A Boolean. When app is started by being passed as parameter to the default app, this property is true in the main process, otherwise it is undefined.

#### app.isPackaged

A Boolean property that returns true if the app is packaged, false otherwise. For many apps, this property can be used to distinguish development and production environments.

[From the code](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/db3cf52add2c88f99dc0b6c787ebbe801cc934c0/lib/browser/api/app.ts#L40) - `app.isPackaged` is set when exec file is not `electron` or `electron.exe`.

Note: I know a minor difference is that `process.defaultApp` may be used in the main process only.

Comment: I have asked upstream https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20448

Answer (score 7):

Both can yield the same result, but some extra care has to be taken for the `process.defaultApp` property:

- handle the case where it is `undefined` (by using the `!` operator for instance)
- make use of [remote.process](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remoteprocess) instead of [process](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#process) in a renderer process

### Main process

```
var isPackaged = !process.defaultApp;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var isPackaged = require('electron').app.isPackaged;
```

### Renderer process

```
var isPackaged = !require('electron').remote.process.defaultApp;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var isPackaged = require('electron').remote.app.isPackaged;
```

**Edit**:

Some extra information, although not 100% crystal clear, about why the `app.isPackaged` property had to be added can be found in the related pull request's conversation: [add app.isPackaged #12656](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/12656)

Comment: Well, you have answered what I have not asked, see the Note: in the question. The only relevant part is the link to the [#12656](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/12656). Make this part as a main answer, move it to the top and remove the rest or change it to some kind of Note: (make it less significant).