# Detect if bundled with javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, bundle, vite, rollupjs

How can I check if my JS app has been bundled with vite/rollup?

```js
const isBuilt = vite.isBuilt() // too easy
const rolledUp = rollup.hasRolled() // too easy, too
const isBundled = someCoolApi.isBundled() // does it exist?
```

With electron you can use [`app.isPackaged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179379/electron-difference-between-process-defaultapp-and-app-ispackaged) to check if the app has been packaged.

Comment: In what environment do you want to check this?

Comment: @code In the browser

Comment: seems odd you would need to check this if you wrote the app. :)

Comment: I know this probably isn't exactly what you want, but why exactly do you need to know? There might be a better way, and if there was a solution to this it would be extremely hacky and unreliable.

Comment: @code Would you know a way for node? I want to enable logging in development and disable in production. By default at least. Currently using `location.hostname === "localhost"` as a proxy. Maybe sth. involving `import.meta` or detecting a transformation the bundler does. E.g. `const isBundled = (() => "" + "").toString().length < 13`. It would become `()=>""`of length 6. Would like documentation on these transformations though.

Comment: See [this page](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html); plenty of options, including `import.meta.env.MODE`, `import.meta.env.DEV`, and `import.meta.env.PROD`.